# ejecutar procedimiento almacenado de SQLServer y MySQL desde Java

Tags: java, mysql, sql-server

buenas días/tardes/noches a la hora que vean este post el asunto es que no conozco la sintaxis para llamar un procedimiento almacenado de SQLServer desde java ejemplo

```
//para llamar a un una sentencia insert/update/delete/select utilizo
PrepareStatement stInsert=con.PrepareStatement("INSERT INTO ejemplo VALUES(?,?,?)");
```

pero para como puedo hacer para un procedimiento almacenado o que sintaxis lleva tanto en caso de SQLServer como de MySQL?

De antemano gracias

Comment: espero que estés bien; podrías explicar cuál es tu dificultad? saber cuál es el código para consultar algo de la base de datos? o guardar algo? Saludos.

Comment: la duda es como es la sintaxis para llamar un procedimiento almacenado de SQLServer desde java por que los prepareStatement se usan para sentencias completas de SQLServer pero para un procedimiento almacenado como seria? espero te quede un poco mas claro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes utilizar:

```
PrepareStatement stInsert=con.PrepareStatement("CALL dbo.stored_procedure()");
```

Aquí puedes ver unos ejemplos:
https://revistadigital.inesem.es/informatica-y-tics/procedimientos-almacenados-de-sql-server-desde-microsoft-access/

https://www.adictosaltrabajo.com/tutoriales/usando-callable-statements-to-execute-stored-procedure/

https://www.lawebdelprogramador.com/foros/Java/1439939-Procedimientos-Almacenados-con-SQL-Server-desde-Java.html

Comment: muchas gracias funciono perfecto te lo agradezco mucho